# Admin managed outlook addin protection from removing by the user

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an use case where the Admin managed add-in shouldn't be disabled by the user as it requires compliance in monitoring sending mails.
Is there an option in Microsoft 365 admin center or somewhere else the admin can prevent user from removing the add-in ?

I can't test this myself as I am a developer looking at feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

By default users are not able to remove or disable such add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

When an admin installs the addin, it is installed as an optional addin which can be removed my the user.
Admin can edit the addin setting in Exchange Admin Centre to make it `Mandatory` addin.
These are the three options Available to admin:

1. Optional: Enabled by default but user can Disable them
2. Optional: Disabled by default but user can Enable them
3. Mandatory: User can't Disable them.